# ConnectWise REST API - getting "Length cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: length"

Tags: rest, postman

I am getting:

> "Length cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: length"

message while calling the ConnectWise REST service. For example:

https://api-na.myconnectwise.net/v2022_2/apis/3.0/company/companies/

I am passing `clientid`, Basic base64(companyid+publickey:privatekey) in headers, it appears that the authorization pass (no Unauthorized message) but getting the message:

> "Length cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: length"

Please take a look at the attached screen capture of the POSTMAN request.

If I do not use the authorization header but use Authorization > Basic Auth with Username = companyid + Public Key and Passsword = Private Key then I get an Unauthorized message.

ConnectWise docs talk about creating Service Boards and ITSupport Portal. Do we need to create these two and any other setup?

I am provided with `clientid`, public and private key, and not sure whether Service Boards and ITSupport Portal are created or not.

Hoping to get some insight from you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generating the Base64 encoded authentication token, I inadvertently swapped the positions of the "+" and ":" symbols in the format "company_id:public_key+private_key" instead of the correct "company_id+public_key:private_key".

Please review your authentication token once more.